# Weird white ball/crystal like formations on RXbar

Tags: mold

I am a fan of RX bars and have been eating them for a while now, but I've never seen something like this before. After browsing through the internet, I'm wondering if this is related to 'sugar bloom' on chocolate or sugar crystals that form on old dates, since both chocolate and dates are ingredients for these bars. I am wondering if I have to throw these all out or can eat them. I unpacked two of these bars in a set of 20 bars, so I really don't want to throw them out but I don't want to eat something that will do me no good. Most of these form on the packaging and towards one of the corners only, and there are only very few that are actually attached to the bar. Here are pictures for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second picture makes them look wet.  Are they? What conditions have the bars been kept in?  If you've got another, can you check very carefully before opening that it's still sealed?  Similar bars often have enough air in there that you can tell by squeezing

Comment: That looks an awful lot like it melted and resolidified to me. You might post the ingredients and nutrition information? Because that really looks like melted cocoa butter or a similar fat on the wrapper.

Comment: @ChrisH It looks glossy, but it definitely wasn't water. More like oil. They were just sitting on a rack in my living room. I've checked a few others and they had similar conditions and seemed well-sealed.

Comment: @kitukwfyer yeah I think that's the case. I live in LA so I think the temp diff should be relatively stable throughout the day and also the year, so I'm not sure what would have caused this.

Comment: Honestly? Storage in a warehouse without climate control or shipping container overnight would be all it takes. I don't know anything about the climate of LA, but if it gets 20 degrees warmer throughout the day and drops off at night, that's plenty variation to melt some fat and resolidify.

Answer (score 3):

That's most likely sugar or fat bloom which is fine to eat. It happens (most often on cheaper chocolates) when it's kept in warm conditions (like an shipping warehouse) and the sugars crystalize on the surface.  See more here: https://www.myrecipes.com/ingredients/what-is-that-white-stuff-on-chocolate

Comment: Yeah I saw this as well but it seemed way too pronounced to be the same thing. I just cleaned them off and gave it a go because nothing smelled funky, and turns out nothing is wrong (at least post 4 months since eating it!)